# C# Compile Issue

Tags: c#

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for 'BobTyler.Program' threw an exception.

'BobTyler.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Any chance to see your code, explain what are you trying to do, ask a normal question, things like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you´ve got a configuration setting in your BobTyler.exe.config (/app.config in the solution project) that isn't of a proper type. Check all entries under  and make sure that they´re mapped to proper types.